# Return N number of rows based on input sent, if 0 return all rows

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a requirement to pass the number of rows to be returned as a parameter. i.e from a table i have to return the rows based on input parameter.

If 5 , then show top 5 rows. But in case of 0 is sent, it have to show all the rows.

```
Create Procedure Get_Employee
    @Input int
As
Begin
    select top @Input * 
    from employee
End
```

Please help me on this , i cannot depend on the identity column as we may have to delete few rows in between.

Answer (score 1):

First, using `top x` without using `order by` means you are basically selecting x arbitrary records from the table (please note that arbitrary is not the same as random).
For more information, read Aaron Bertrand's [Bad habits to kick : relying on undocumented behavior.](https://sqlblog.org/2010/02/08/bad-habits-to-kick-relying-on-undocumented-behavior)

Second, the simplest solution would be to replace `0` with the number of rows in the table inside your stored procedure:

```
Create Procedure Get_Employee
    @Input int
As
Begin
    if @Input <= 0 begin -- Note: handling a negative input like it's zero...
        set @Input = (select count(*) from employee)
    end

    select top (@Input) * 
    from employee
    order by Id -- or whatever column you want use to order by
End
```